# Ionic React handle Hardware BackButton {Android or IOS } For Routes and any other Overlay component such as Modal, ActionSheet, etc

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic5

I want to handle BackButton like a pro in Ionic React app, but i found myself doing something like this

```
 if (Capacitor.isNative) {
    App.addListener("backButton", () => {
      if (history.location.pathname === "/") {
        App.exitApp();
      } else if (history.location.pathname === "/tab/home") {
        App.exitApp();
      } else if(history.location.pathname === "/tab/brand" ||history.location.pathname === "/tab/search" || history.location.pathname === "/tab/chats" || history.location.pathname === "/tab/notifications" ||  history.location.pathname === "/profile") {
        history.goBack();
      }
    });
  }
```

I think the useCase is ok, but the question is what if i have something like a modal or overlay stuff, ActionSheet and the likes, and `HardwarebackButton` is pressed?

Answer (score 2):

The `addListener` method can take the `canGoBack` parameter indicates whether the browser can go back in history. It becomes false when the history stack is on the first entry.

Let's jump into the code:

```
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

// ...
const history = useHistory();
const location = useLocation();

if (Capacitor.isNative) {
    App.addListener('backButton', ({ canGoBack }) => {
        if (!canGoBack || location.pathname === '/tab/home') {
            App.exitApp();
        } else {
            history.goBack();
        }
    });
}
```

I wish I can help you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ionic-react, but though there's better code that could be simpler and the one ur using.

```
  if (Capacitor.isNative) {
    App.addListener("backButton", () => {
        const have_stacks = window.history.length; 
        have_stacks <= 1 ? App.exitApp() : history.goBack();
    });
  }
```

Using "<= 1" depends on ur case, but its mostly known in ionic routes that history of stack of main page is 0 but here i set it for ur case 1, though u can change to "==0" if it didn't work as needed.

Plus for modal, u can add a service and set a variable if a modal is open and then u add above const have stacks, if modal is open then close modal, else execute the below code i already set.